# Безопасна загрузка файлов

Tags: php

Вот мой обработчик загрузки картинок всего двух типов.
Есть подозрение что это не безопасно.
Вот код:

```
function format($file){
$valid_types=array("image/jpg","image/jpeg","image/png");
if(in_array($file['type'],$valid_types)) return 1;
else return 0;
}
$PATH=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/ava/";
if(isset($_GET['down'])){
$image=$_FILES['image'];
$image['name']=text($image['name']);
$dirka=$PATH.basename($image['name']);
if(!format($image)) msg('Такой формат не подходит!');
else{
if($image['size']>200000) msg('Файл много весит!');
else{
if(!move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'],$dirka)) msg('Ошибка загрузки!');
else{
$avka=$PATH.$user['ava'];
unlink($avka);
q("UPDATE `user` SET `ava`='".$image['name']."' WHERE `id`='".$user['id']."'");
reload('gamer.php?id='.$user['id']);
}
}
}
}
```

Прошу сказать что тут не так и как обезопасить себя от шелов.

Comment: тут не только шелл, тут sql инъекция вдобавок.

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь..